# Get the type of React components propTypes definition

Tags: reactjs, components

Suppose the following code:

```
TestComponent.propTypes = {
  text: React.PropTypes.string,
  myEnum: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['News', 'Photos'])
};
```

I did the following in another file (that was using TestComponent):

```
if (TestComponent.propTypes.text === React.PropTypes.string) {...}

if (TestComponent.propTypes.myEnum === React.PropTypes.oneOf) {...}
```

Well, to my satisfaction the first if worked. But the second if never returned true. I tried to modify it to the syntax below, but it did not help.

```
if (TestComponent.propTypes.myEnum === React.PropTypes.oneOf(['News', 'Photos'])) {...}
```

So, the question is: What mechanism is there to discover the type of a prop?
I know that React tests the value of a prop against the propType to validate it. However, I need access to the 'expected type' as well to do my stuff.

BTW, here's an excerpt from the React code that validates propTypes (shortened for the sake of brevity):

```
function createPrimitiveTypeChecker(expectedType) {
  function validate(props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName){      
    var propValue = props[propName];
    var propType = getPropType(propValue);
    if (propType !== expectedType) {
      // return some Error
     }
     return null;
  }
  return createChainableTypeChecker(validate);
}
```

As you can see the parameter of the outer function is expectedType. It is used in the inner validate function (if (propType !== expectedType)). However, React does not save the expectedType into a member variable so that it can be accessed by outside code. So how does outside code figure out the type of the propType??

My point is not to 'validate' a specific value for the prop. That gets taken care of by React very well. My point is to do some specific logic depending on the prop type, which I can't get to with types like anyOf, objectOf, shape, etc.

Any thoughts, suggestions??

Comment: See my response for an explanation.
There is a feature request and a PR in progress to fix this, see here and +1: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8310

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, you can't compare these, because they point to different functions. When you call `oneOf`, it returns another function.

**Explanation**: The problem here is that `React.PropTypes.oneOf` is the function `createEnumTypeChecker`.

Whereas `React.PropTypes.myEnum` will contain the return value of calling the `oneOf` function - because in the `propTypes` definition you have to actually call `oneOf()`.

The result of calling `oneOf()` is a different function, declared inside `createChainableTypeChecker()`.

Unfortunately, your second try, won't work either because these functions are different, they're created each time you call `oneOf()`. See `createChainableTypeChecker` in `ReactPropTypes.js`

```
 var chainedCheckType = checkType.bind(null, false);
 chainedCheckType.isRequired = checkType.bind(null, true);

 return chainedCheckType;
```

**Solution:** I propose you test the names of the functions. This will prove that this is a valid React Prop type.

```
// returns false
React.PropTypes.oneOf(['myArr']) === React.PropTypes.oneOf(['myArr'])

// returns true
React.PropTypes.oneOf(['myArr']).name == React.PropTypes.oneOf(['myArr']).name

// this should return true in your case:
if ( TestComponent.propTypes.myEnum.name === React.PropTypes.oneOf().name )
```

Unfortunately, all non-primitive React *propTypes* use `createChainableTypeChecker`, and this always returns a function with the name `checkType`. If this name would be different for each *propType*, then you would be able to check which type is used. As it is now, you can't know if it's `oneOf`, `objectOf` or any of the others, including `any`.