# How can I get type and if the prop is required from prop-types package?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a React Component whose prop-types I've defined. Whenever I'm logging out the `propTypes` in React. it logs me out a function which is possibly the validator. I want to print the propType and whether the prop is required or not (e.g. *prop1: {required: true, value: 5}*) at this point. How can I do that?

```
class Component extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
     console.log(Component.propTypes.prop1);
   }
}

Component.propTypes = {
    prop1: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    prop2: PropTypes.string
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the type of React components propTypes definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37470610/get-the-type-of-react-components-proptypes-definition)

Comment: @HarishSoni thank you for pointing this question to other one but seems like the question is very old when React had the propTypes package. Now, the propTypes is a separate package, do you think they have given such construct?